# How do I live check shipping price from MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How do I live check my shipping cost from MySQL?

Example :

```
Shipping Cost Table

+----+------------+----------+-------+
| id | value_from | value_to | price |
+----+------------+----------+-------+
|  1 |          1 |       10 |   100 |
|  2 |         11 |       20 |   200 |
+----+------------+----------+-------+
```

---

```
Product Name : Shirt | Quantity : 2 | Price : 100 | Subtotal : 200
Product Name : Shoes | Quantity : 1 | Price : 150 | Subtotal : 150
Product Name : Pants | Quantity : 3 | Price : 50  | Subtotal : 150

Total : 500
Total quantity : 6

Shipping Cost
(•) 100 (radio checked) //Get value from MySQL if quantity >= value_from, shipping price = 100
Total price : 600
```

If my I change my product quantity like:

```
Product Name : Shirt | Quantity : 5 | Price : 100 | Subtotal : 500
Product Name : Shoes | Quantity : 1 | Price : 150 | Subtotal : 150
Product Name : Pants | Quantity : 5 | Price : 50  | Subtotal : 250

Total : 900
Total quantity : 11
```

`Total quantity = 11` shipping price on radio button will live change to 200 like:

```
Shipping Cost
(•) 200 (radio checked)
Total price : 1100
```

My code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbrnb62b/) **(Only HTML and live change Javascript not live check shipping price from PHP & MySQL)**

Comment: Send an AJAX call to check for a flag value or to check if the same value is present every `x` units of time?

Comment: @SatejS Send `Total quantity` to check for get shipping price in PHP file for check shipping price and send the correct shipping price back.

Comment: Both the quantity and Price can change, correct?Or just the qty?

Comment: @SatejS On my code in jsfiddle `Total quantity` can change and when `Total quantity` has been changed shipping price will changed too. Example : If I change product quantity and `Total quantity` = 15 shipping price will live change to 200 and `Total price` will live changed too.

Comment: Correct, checked that.so when you say you want to check shipping cost from MySQL, are you talking of the total cost, or the individual prices or what exactly?

Comment: @SatejS This `Shipping Cost (•) 200 (radio checked)`

Answer (score 0):

1. If your Shipping Cost Table is small and simple, you can fetch all data into JS object. Ex: 
   `shippingCost = {10: 100, 20: 200}; // {value_to: price}`

Then compare total quantity to get the price.

```
function getPrice(quality) {
    var currentPrice = 0;
    for (value in shippingCost) {
        if (quality <= value) {
            currentPrice = shippingCost[value];
        }
    }
    if (currentPrice == 0) {// There is an exception here, the quality is not matched with shipping cost table}
}
```

Note: I didn't test with this code, sorry if it throws some error, but it's an idea.

2. If the shipping cost rule is more complex, consider to use Ajax to send the current quality into server, then using PHP & MySQL to calculate the price and return to client.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive realtime-change from MySQL, you need use websocket in javascript, and use a socket library for PHP to send response to client.

See example from http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world